# Swift - Google Map crashes with 'unexpectedly found nil' error

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to set a `GoogleMap` to a `UIView` and add it as a Subview. However, when running the app I get this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

It crashes at code line:

```
mapView.camera = camera
```

**Here's my full ViewController code:**

```
class LocationViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 15.4989, longitude: 73.8278, zoom: 6)
        mapView.camera = camera
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        self.view.addSubview(self.mapView)
    }
}
```

I went through a few other similar SO threads and all of them have the same code. In my case the UI freezes and crashes with this error. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Yes, I have set the UIView's custom class as `GMSMapView`

Comment: in which line you got error?

Comment: @Jecky At `mapView.camera = camera`

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: check your IBOutlet connections in Storyboard

Comment: Have you given the GMSMapView class to the view in the Storyboard

Comment: @Harish yes I have

Comment: then , it's good .

Answer (score 0):

Could you please use below code and try:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 15.4989, longitude: 73.8278, zoom: 6)
        mapView.camera = camera
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        self.view.addSubview(self.mapView)
    }
```

Comment: What is the change you have made?

Comment: Your mapview frame

Comment: The code is a little bit different in swift-3 bro :/

Comment: Still crashes and should it be a weak or strong reference?

Comment: It must be weak and if you have connected it using storyboard then refer my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131541/discussion-between-dheeraj-d-and-rickgrimeslikeswalkersoup).

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it like this

you have to give frame to `GMSMapview`

Here in this line `self.view.bounds` , you have to set your custom `view`

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 15.4989,
                                      longitude:  73.8278,
                                      zoom: 6)
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: camera)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax in swift 3.0

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) 
{
    print(locations)
    mapview.delegate = self
 currentLocation =     CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:CLLocationDegrees(locations[0].coordinate.latitude), longitude:CLLocationDegrees(locations[0].coordinate.longitude))
    mapview.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget:locations[0].coordinate, zoom: 10.0)
mapview.isMyLocationEnabled = true
}
```